# How to prevent pre-loading of my modal when it is definied of false in localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I created a modal that opens when it has not been read yet and which no longer opens when it has been read. I have stored the value false in the localStorage and if it has been read it opens and then closes. I wish it would never open if it hasn't been read.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";

export default function Modal() {
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const isRead = localStorage.getItem("value");
    if (isRead){
  setIsOpen(false)
    } else if (!isRead){setIsOpen(true)};
  },[])

return (
  <>
    {isOpen && (
      <div>
        <button
          className="close" onClick={()=>{ setIsOpen(false) || localStorage.setItem("value", false)}}
        />
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
          officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </div>
      )}

      {!isOpen && (
        <Loader
          className="spinner"
          type="ThreeDots"
          color="#F5F5F5"
          height={100}
          width={100}
          timeout={1500}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";

export default function Modal() {
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const isRead = localStorage.getItem("value");
    if (!isRead){
  setIsOpen(true)
    }
  },[])

return (
  <>
    {isOpen && (
      <div>
        <button
          className="close" onClick={()=>{ setIsOpen(false) || localStorage.setItem("value", true)}}
        />
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
          officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </div>
      )}

      {!isOpen && (
        <Loader
          className="spinner"
          type="ThreeDots"
          color="#F5F5F5"
          height={100}
          width={100}
          timeout={1500}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is on this line

```
else if (!isRead){setIsOpen(true)}
```

Once `isRead` returns `false` i.e the `modal` was read and then you add the `not` operator it'll return `true` and that will set `setIsOpen` to `true` which opens the modal.

You can try this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";

export default function Modal() {
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const isRead = localStorage.getItem("value");
    if (isRead){
  setIsOpen(false)
    }
  },[])

return (
  <>
    {isOpen && (
      <div>
        <button
          className="close" onClick={()=>{ setIsOpen(false) || localStorage.setItem("value", true)}}
        />
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
          officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </div>
      )}

      {!isOpen && (
        <Loader
          className="spinner"
          type="ThreeDots"
          color="#F5F5F5"
          height={100}
          width={100}
          timeout={1500}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is correct 'else' is not necessary. But the display remains the same.